# redshift - Not able to apply listagg function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am getting error when trying to use `listagg` function.

**Query**

```
select 
        a.user_name, 
        listagg(a.group_name::text)
within group (order by a.group_name) as group_name
from (
        SELECT 
                usename as user_name, 
                groname as group_name
        FROM 
                pg_user 
        join
                 pg_group
        on 
                pg_user.usesysid = ANY(pg_group.grolist) AND 
                pg_group.groname in (SELECT DISTINCT pg_group.groname from pg_group) 
     )a
     
group by user_name
```

**Error**

> [Code: 500310, SQL State: XX000]  Amazon Invalid operation: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc;

None of the value is `null`.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers that helped you. You have only accepted 1 answer in your last 10 questions. Not accepting useful answers might discourage people from helping you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just like there are some functions that can only be run on the leader node there are some that can only be run on compute nodes - listagg() is one of these.  If you need to run listagg() on leader data there are a few approaches you can use:  (sorry I'm not on a cluster now so cannot test these directly - I saw your question was aging and thought I'd get you started.  Grain of salt as I also cannot directly observe your issue but I think I've know what is going on.)

1. You can use a cursor to save the data from the leader node and use
   this as the source for listagg().  A stored procedure can
   streamline this.  There are examples of this on stackoverflow.
2. You can make a temp table out of the leader node data and use this
   in listagg() but I expect you will need to exit(unload) and
   reenter(copy) the cluster to do this.

There just isn't a direct path from leader-node-only results to the compute nodes without some sort of this kind of push-up.  Consequence of the large networked cluster architecture of Redshift.

UPDATE

I got some cluster time and there are several unexpected issues with this one.  grolist is an array type that isn't generally support cluster wide and the need to user pg_group as source are key ones.  So this is going to require #1 AND #2 from above.

The process goes like this:

1. Define cursor to hold the result of the pg_user / pg_group join select statement
2. Move cursor results to temp table
3. Use temp table as source to outer (list_agg()) select

A stored procedure can be written to do #1 and #2 which streamlines things.  So you end up with the following SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure make_user_group()
AS
$$
DECLARE 
  row record;
BEGIN
  create temp table user_group (user_name varchar(256),group_name varchar(256));
  for row in SELECT 
                usename::text as user_name, 
                groname::text as group_name
        FROM 
                pg_user 
        join
                 pg_group
        on 
                pg_user.usesysid = ANY(pg_group.grolist) AND 
                pg_group.groname in (SELECT DISTINCT pg_group.groname from pg_group)
   LOOP
    INSERT INTO user_group(user_name,group_name) VALUES (row.user_name,row.group_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call make_user_group();

select 
        user_name, 
        listagg(group_name::text, ', ')
within group (order by group_name) as group_name
from user_group
group by user_name;
```

Clearly the stored procedure only needs to be created once but called every time the temp table needs to be created.

Comment: I don't think I understand everything. However I created cursor and tried to use in subquery and it's giving error.

Comment: @GaurangShah I updated the answer with SQL and a more detailed explanation of the solution.  Hope this helps

Comment: Very nice solution. Got my upvote